# unix date command with nanosecond precision. Input parameter

Tags: date, unix

I'm having difficulty parsing an inputted date with nanosecond precision:

```
date: invalid date `15-OCT-18 12:40:01:000203570 AM'
```

Yet when I drop the nanoseconds, it works fine:

```
$ date -d "15-OCT-18 12:40:01 AM" +"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S %p"
15-10-2018 00:40:01 AM
```

Looking the docs its suggests uppercase N is to be used for ns

Even when I drop the Ns it generates the ns for me

```
$ date -d "15-OCT-18 12:40:01 AM" +"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S:%N %p"
15-10-2018 00:40:01:000000000 AM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be in the format

`date -d "15-OCT-18 12:40:01.000203570 AM" +"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S:%N %p"`

Data needs to have . instead of : spearating seconds and ns

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the : before the Nanoseconds identifier with .(dot)

```
> date -d"$(echo "15-OCT-18 12:40:01:000203570 AM" | sed 's/:/./3')" +"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S.%N %p"
15-10-2018 00:40:01.000203570 AM
>
```